# Can't generate a signed APK

Tags: java, android, gradle

I just upgraded my Android Studio to version `3.3.1` and also migrated my project to `AndroidX` now the issue is when I try to generate a signed APK for the project it keeps failing with this error message:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsignerfailed with exit code 1 :
  >   jarsigner: key associated with mykolo not a private key

I'm certain that the password key and alias I am using are all correct so I would appreciate anyhelp

Comment: I had similar problem, this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54640805/1235910

Answer (score 0):

On the terminal enter :
keytool -v -list -keystore path_to_yout_keystore

you will get a warning like that

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore path_to_yout_keystore -destkeystore path_to_yout_keystore -deststoretype pkcs12"

with this command
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore path_to_yout_keystore -destkeystore path_to_yout_keystore -deststoretype pkcs12

you will get the recommanded format keystore