# Error while build an signed apk. The error is "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, keystore, signed-apk

I have tried so many ways... And I have tried so many comments, but I got the same error. But my passwords are correct. When I created that, I noted that. I have tried without entering a password in another(keystore1) keystore, I got the mentioned error "Cannot load key store: keystore password was incorrect". But this(problem having keystore) keystore throws "**Cannot load key store: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect**". Could anyone help with this? Whatever comment I have used throws the same error.
Please help me with this...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68307826/9722336

Comment: Also check other values like alias

Comment: When I click the alias area it throws same error.

Comment: Did you try the link mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. I got the error below "Execution failed for task ':student:packageProdRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key0 from store "/home/usr/keystore.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"