# Android Studio cannot recover key from Keystore

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

As the title says, Android Studio cannot recover the key from the Keystore to generate a release signed APK. I've had two teammates try with the same credentials I'm using and they were both able to generate the signed APK without problems.

I've checked most of the links here in SO and none of those solved my problem. I've payed most attention to the below as the best suspect for the problem:
[Android Studio: cannot recover key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997688/android-studio-cannot-recover-key)

My current setup is a Windows 10 laptop, so I thought that this could be a Windows thing (my teammates have a Mac and an Ubuntu Laptop). Next thing I did was set up a VM with Linux Mint and checkout the project and build, but I have the exact same error.

Screenshots:

[Using a wrong password on purpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAEF7.png)

[Using correct password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmuDB.png)

Comment: what did you give as `alias`?

Comment: the name of the app

Comment: I have been facing same issue.Anyone can get rid out of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only thing that ended up fixing this permanently was a change in dev environment (using another laptop in my case, but the change wasn't triggered by this bug tho)

Comment: Was this issue resolved?