# Android Key store passwords are correct but Cannot recover key

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

I remember the passwords. I always use same key store passwords for every application.
I have tried every single solution but issue is still there.

I also checked the passwords for the previous log files and it is the same as i remember.
Kindly help me out I want to give an update and I am stuck here "Cannot Recover Key".

Comment: This post has a procedure that might help: [Android Studio: cannot recover key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997688/android-studio-cannot-recover-key)

Comment: @Elletlar How to use keytool to in the above solution. I have never used it before.

Comment: @Elletlar How to use keytool to in the above solution. I have never used it before.

Comment: keytool is here: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin on a windows machine. The link above should have the command to run.