# How can I solve this issue "Cannot recover key" in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

When I created a new `key.jks` I always get an error message that says

> "Cannot recover key"

I made different keys but always get the same error. How can I solve that?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: One thing that helped me to make a new keystore work instead of getting "probably was tempered with" was to 1.) clean project 2.) invalidate and restart

Comment: Just be aware that the root cause is either Key Password or Keystore Password is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by "**Key Password** and/or **Keystore Password** Mis-matching". You have to supply both password correctly.

See more discussions here: [Android Studio: cannot recover key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997688/android-studio-cannot-recover-key)

Comment: I think the key password and keystore password are okay, because in one project the key works perfectly but in other projects it throw me "Cannot recover key"