# Android Keystore Cannot recover key

Tags: android, kotlin, android-keystore

I've developed and uploaded my app to Google Play Store, and now I am trying to upload an update for it but Android Studio wont let me create a signed APK, I am sure that my passwords and alias were all correct.

Will there be another way to fix this? Or is there's a way to transfer Keystore to another Keystore so I can update my App on the Google Play Store

PS. I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox and still have the same issue.

Any help and/or ideas are appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997688/android-studio-cannot-recover-key see if that helps

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997688/android-studio-cannot-recover-key)?

Comment: will check that out

Comment: issues still persist tried both links guide

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. When you generate signed bundle or apk you should erase your key store password and alias after that you should re-enter your key store password and alias again. Kinda strange bug but it's worked for me.

Comment: Tried that didnt work, also tried to generate on other computer, and updated the Android Studio still didnt work on my end. This is kinda frustrating few feeks ako this is working without fail. Any other tip/idea to resolve this?